# type object 'UploadSerializers' has no attribute 'HyperlinkedModelSerializer'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

trying to do the Django Rest Framework foreign key serialization ,,however I got this error,

> models.py

```
class ProductsTbl(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': "這 model number 已經被註冊了 ."
        }
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    feature = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    release = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    twtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    hktime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    jptime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    suggest = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    useredit = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''

        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()

        return super(ProductsTbl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(['thing_images', instance.thing.slug, filename])


class Upload(models.Model):
    thing = models.ForeignKey(ProductsTbl, related_name="uploads")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, verbose_name='Image')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Upload, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.image:
            image = Image.open(self.image)
            i_width, i_height = image.size
            max_size = (640, 480)

            if i_width > 1000:
                image.thumbnail(max_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
                image.save(self.image.path)
```

> api/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


UserModel = get_user_model()

class UploadSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('image',)



class ProductsTblSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    uploads = UploadSerializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ProductsTbl
        fields = ('model_number',
        'created',
        'name',
        'release',
        'twtime',
        'hktime',
        'shtime',
        'jptime',
        'feature',
        'material',
        'suggest',
        'description',
        'cataloggroup',
        'place',
        'scale',
        'slug',
        'user',
        'uploads')
```

> api/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^productsTbls/$', views.ProductsTblListView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_list'),
    url(r'^productsTbls/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ProductsTblDetailView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_detail'),
    url(r'^productsTbls/pdelete/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/$',views.api_delete_product,name='api_delete_p'),
    url(r'^productsTbls/register/$', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name='productsTbls_register'),
]
```

> api/views.py

```
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny




class ProductsTblListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsTbl.objects.order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = ProductsTblSerializer



class ProductsTblDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ProductsTbl.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductsTblSerializer
```

however ,,if I changed the `api/serializers.py` like below

```
......
class ProductsTblSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    uploads = UploadSerializers(many=True,read_only=True)
......
```

I can see http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/productsTbls/  my page come out,,but without the image link,how can I show the image link in `"uploads":[]`? thank you (django rest framework 3.4)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've inherited your `UploadSerializer` class from serializers.ModelSerializer, not from `serializers.HyperLinkedModelSerializer`

```
class UploadSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('image',)
```

So when you try to use it as

`uploads = UploadSerializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)`

it doesn't have that attribute.

If you make your initial declaration of `UploadSerializers` inherit from the hyperlink class, it should work.

```
class UploadSerializers(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('image',)
```

Then you should be able to use:

`uploads = UploadSerializers(many=True,read_only=True)`